# Does equation $x=\frac{1}{1+e^x}$ have a closed-form representation?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Basically , I was messing around with the logistic function $$\frac{1}{1+e^x}$$ and I found that when infinitely recursing the answer back into the function, the answer converged to a number.

> Basically, what I'm trying to find is a non decimal value of $x$ , where $$x=\frac{1}{1+e^x}$$

Does anyone know how to go about this?

Comment: It is unlikely that the solution of this equation has a closed form. Maybe, the Lambert-W-function helps.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha does not find a closed-form solution, which is a bad sign.

Comment: @Peter You're right, my bad.  I misinterpreted the question.  I have deleted my answer.

Comment: A better problem would focus on proving that the *equation* has exactly one *solution*, and showing how quickly the fixed point iteration you describe converges to that solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rwrite the equation as
$$e^{-x}=-\frac x{x-1}$$ which measn that there is a solution in terms of the [generalized Lambert function](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3999) (have a look at equation $(4)$). This is nice to know.

Consider that you look for the zero of function
$$f(x)=x-\frac{1}{1+e^x}$$
Expand it as a series around $x=0$
$$f(x)=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{5 x}{4}+O\left(x^3\right)$$ So, $x_0=\frac 25 $ which is "close" to $\frac 1e$.
Now, expand again around $x_0$ and use series reversion to get
$$x\sim\frac{e+e^{1+\frac{1}{e}}+e^{\frac{1}{e}}}{e+3
   e^{1+\frac{1}{e}}+e^{1+\frac{2}{e}}}=0.401038$$ while the "exact" solution is $0.401058$

**Edit**

I do not see how we could get a closed form for the solution. We can get very close solutions using series expansions of $x(1+e^x)$ built at $x=0$ followed by series reversion to get
$$x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{b_n} 2^{-n} $$but this does not converge very fast.

I gave the solution to a friend of mine who enjoys this kind of problems and he came back with the *approximation*
$$x\sim \exp\left(\frac{23}{30}+\frac{1}{15 e}-\frac{29 e}{30}+\frac{1}{6 \pi }+\frac{\pi }{2} \right)\pi ^{\left(\frac{4 e}{15}-\frac{17}{30}\right)}\sin ^{\frac{8}{5}}(e \pi ) (-\cos (e \pi ))^{\frac{31}{30}}$$ which gives $20$ exact significant figures; for this value 
$$x(1+e^x)-1=-1.176\times 10^{-19}$$

Comment: Thank you!
Is there no way to represent the exact x value?

Comment: @MrChikn. The "exact" value, I don't think. i shall try to give tomorrow a much more accurate explicit approximation.. The problem is very interesting because we are "close" to Lambert function.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the equation

$$x=\frac{1}{1+e^x}$$

does not permit a close-from solution. However, the close-to-linear functional behavior around the root allows decent approximate close-form representation, such as,

$$x = \frac{2+2\sqrt e}{2+5\sqrt e+e}$$

which is approximately 0.408, compared to the exact numerical solution of 0.401.

Comment: Does this mean that the number is transendental?

Comment: And also, why does it have no closed form solution? Sorry if it is a lot. I'm only a high schooler with a curious mind

Comment: You have to define what you mean by "closed form solution". One could say, $x$ is the solution to the given equation and that would be a perfectly valid definition. However, I think you more mean some combination of trig equations, polynomials, and roots. I would investigate https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_equation for more information.